# How to get multiple objects in cocos2d to react to touches

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I have the following code in my game:

```
int x = 50;  
int y = 400;  
for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++) {  
    if (x+54 > self.boundingBox.size.width) {  
        x = 50;  
        y -= 70;  
        ccDrawCircle(CGPointMake(x, y), 20, 3.14, 100, NO);  
    } else {  
        ccDrawCircle(CGPointMake(x, y), 20, 3.14, 100, NO);  
        x += 72;  
    }  
}
```

How can I get each of these circles to react to touches? Specifically I'm thinking about giving them a button press effect (shrinks on touch, resize on end touch), and also change colors on touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Cocos, it is easiest to make your circles CCSprites and then respond to touches on those sprites, using this method in your layer:

`-(BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{`

Then, iterate through your sprites using a common technique like this:

`isTouchHandled= CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingbox], [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:[touch locationInView: [touch view]]]);`

If `isTouchHandled` is TRUE, then you can do what you need to do with that sprite or anything else.

Note that you can use this method either in the layer itself or in a subclass of the sprite, and in whichever you choose, you must register the node with the touch dispatcher with this in the `init` or somewhere:

`[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];`

Comment: create just one little transparent png, then use CCSpriteBatchNode so the system only draws 1 sprite but replicates it without using additional rendering resources

Comment: sorry, not sure if I follow that. Could you maybe provide an example please?